# Criar um model de um form web

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, model

Estou montando uma página web com .Net Core e eu tenho um form web que tem muitos campos e eu estava pensando em como pegar todas essas informações preenchidas de forma mais dinâmica, fiz uma pergunta aqui e me deram a sugestão de fazer um model para pegar essas informações, mas sou iniciante e não sei como fazer, já dei uma pesquisada e iniciei também, mas estou recebendo os valores todos `null`, vou deixar +/- como está meu código, Me ajudem por favor.

**MODEL:**

```
public class Persist
{
    public string[] data {get;set;} = {};
}
```

Deixei só um exemplo, pra não ficar extenso, se eu entender um, tento fazer os outros sozinho.

**FORM:**

```
<form method="POST">
    <select class="form-control w-100" id="data2" name="data[2]">            
        <option value="N"> Não analisar</option>            
        <option value="S"> Sim</option>        
    </select>

    <select class="form-control w-100" id="data5" name="data[5]">            
        <option value="N"> Não analisar</option>            
        <option value="S"> Sim</option>        
    </select>

    <select class="form-control w-100" id="data8" name="data[8]">            
        <option value="N"> Não analisar</option>            
        <option value="S"> Sim</option>        
    </select>
</form>
```

**Função que pega os dados:**

```
private static string Save(Models.Persist p)
{
    var teste = p.data[2]; // Dá erro

    return teste;
}
```

Quando eu debugo o código e tento ver o valor de p (o Model), aparecem todas as variáveis, porem todas elas `null`, como eu faço para pegar o valor dos campos?

Sou iniciante.

Grato.

**EDIT:**

Com a modificação do `model`, o valor de `data` agora aparece `{string[0]}`

Comment: @endro, Razor Pages não é?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo sim

Comment: adiciona o resto do exemplo, pq o seu trecho de código não está completo